# Is there a keyboard shortcut to move between Google Chrome screens in OS X?

Tags: macos

<kbd>command</kbd> +  <kbd>`</kbd> (left of the <kbd>1</kbd>) works for other apps, but it doesn't work most of the time for Google Chrome.  Anyone knows of another keyboard shortcut?

Comment: Do you mean between windows, or between tabs? Command + ` is the correct shortcut for switching windows. I don't have any problems with it.

Comment: The trackpad? If you full screen and separate each window.